# Is it possible to store multiple data types in an ArrayList using C#?

Tags: c#

In C#, can I store multiple data types in an ArrayList?
Like;

```
myArrayList.Add(false);
myArrayList.Add("abc");
myarrayList.Add(26);
myArrayList.Add(obj);
```

I know i can make a DataTable or a class for it.

But, please let me know: is this possible? And if so, what are it's De-merits of being a collection class?

Comment: Yes, it's possible (and it will work as typed up!) .. but it's also often a PITA to deal with "a bunch of `object`s" later. Static/strong typing is nice; use it - and to this I suggest using `List<T>` instead of [the old] `ArrayList`.

Comment: What is the use case you are considering here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can store like this

```
ArrayList aa = new ArrayList();
aa.Add(false);
aa.Add(1);
aa.Add("Name");
```

ArrayList belongs to the days that C# didn't have generics. It's deprecated in favor of List. You shouldn't use ArrayList in new code that targets .NET >= 2.0 unless you have to interface with an old API that uses it.

[ArrayList vs List<> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp)

Comment: **Another solution** create generic list of anonymous type. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47885255/2218697).

Answer (score 1):

i guess `List<object>` help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store objects of different types in an ArrayList but, like pst mentioned, it's a pain to deal with them later.

If the values are related in some way you are probably better off writing a class to hold them. This will give you strong typing and the values will be named so someone else looking at the code will have a chance of understanding what's going on.