# Is there a trick in creating a generic list of anonymous type?

Tags: c#, generics, anonymous-types

Sometimes i need to use a Tuple, for example i have list of tanks and their target tanks (they chase after them or something like that ) :

```
List<Tuple<Tank,Tank>> mylist = new List<Tuple<Tank,Tank>>();
```

and then when i iterate over the list i access them by

```
mylist[i].item1 ...
mylist[i].item2 ...
```

It's very confusing and i always forget what is item1 and what is item2, if i could access them by :

```
mylist[i].AttackingTank...
mylist[i].TargetTank...
```

It would be much clearer, is there a way to do it without defining a class:

```
MyTuple
{
public Tank AttackingTank;
public Tank TargetTank;
}
```

I want to avoid defining this class because then i would have to define many different classes in different scenarios, can i do some "trick" and make this anonymous.

Something like :

```
var k = new {Name = "me", phone = 123};
mylist.Add(k);
```

The problem of course that i don't have a type to pass to the List when i define it

Comment: Have you tried the dynamic keyword for the list type?

Comment: What's wrong with defining the class? Seems like the obvious solution. As for needing to `define many different classes`, perhaps there is an inheritance structure that you can exploit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A generic list of anonymous class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612689/a-generic-list-of-anonymous-class)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can create an empty list for anonymous types and then use it, enjoying full intellisense and compile-time checks:

```
var list = Enumerable.Empty<object>()
             .Select(r => new {A = 0, B = 0}) // prototype of anonymous type
             .ToList();

list.Add(new { A = 4, B = 5 }); // adding actual values

Console.Write(list[0].A);
```

Comment: There is a handy Select that converts object to anonymous type, so we get the list of anonymous types , and not the list of objects. This sample compiles just fine.

Comment: Upvoted since this is mostly the same as my answer, and this answer was earlier than mine.

Comment: (After I edited my answer to include another technique, mine is no longer "mostly the same".)

Comment: Is there a performance penalty in accessing or adding items to the list opposed to the naive solution ?

Comment: Compiler generates a class for your anonymous type, so performance is pretty much the same as if you would create a normal class and use it.

Comment: This is fantastic!

Comment: **Another solution** create generic list of anonymous type. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47885255/2218697).

Answer (score 18):

You could use a `List<dynamic>`.

```
 var myList = new List<dynamic>();
 myList.Add(new {Tank = new Tank(), AttackingTank = new Tank()});

 Console.WriteLine("AttackingTank: {0}", myList[0].AttackingTank);
```

Comment: while this will allow you to add items, it does not allow you to assign the reference to an anonymous list.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a hack:

```
var myList = Enumerable.Empty<int>()
    .Select(dummy => new { AttackingTank = default(Tank), TargetTank = default(Tank), })
    .ToList();
```

If `Tank` is a class type, you can write `(Tank)null` instead of `default(Tank)`. You can also use some `Tank` instance you happen to have at hand.

---

EDIT:

Or:

```
var myList = Enumerable.Repeat(
    new { AttackingTank = default(Tank), TargetTank = default(Tank), },
    0).ToList();
```

---

If you make a generic method, you won't have to use `Enumerable.Empty`. It could go like this:

```
static List<TAnon> GetEmptyListWithAnonType<TAnon>(TAnon dummyParameter)
{
    return new List<TAnon>();
}
```

It is to be called with the `TAnon` inferred from usage, of course, as in:

```
var myList = GetEmptyListWithAnonType(new { AttackingTank = default(Tank), TargetTank = default(Tank), });
```

Answer (score 8):

It's worth to note that finally, there is possibility to use such syntax. It had been introduced in C# 7.0

```
var tanks = new List<(Tank AttackingTank, Tank TargetTank)>();

(Tank, Tank) tTank = (new Tank(), new Tank());
tanks.Add(tTank);

var a = tanks[0].AttackingTank;
var b = tanks[0].TargetTank;
```

Comment: I like this and using it in my app, but what is this type of syntax called? I like to do some additional research on it.

Comment: @MikeBarlow-BarDev Microsoft blog names it 
 tuple types and tuple literals https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/

Answer (score 5):

You could just have a generic method that takes a `params` and returns it:

```
public static IList<T> ToAnonymousList<T>(params T[] items)
{
  return items;
}
```

So now you can say:

```
var list=ToAnonymousList
(
  new{A=1, B=2},
  new{A=2, B=2}
);
```

Comment: I'd like return the list variable in a method. The list is an IList<T> but the T is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

How about [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) ?

```
dynamic tuple = new ExpandoObject(); 
tuple.WhatEverYouWantTypeOfTank = new Tank(); // Value of any type
```

**EDITS:**

```
dynamic tuple = new ExpandoObject();
tuple.AttackingTank = new Tank();
tuple.TargetTank = new Tank();

var mylist = new List<dynamic> { tuple };

//access to items
Console.WriteLine(mylist[0].AttackingTank);
```

Comment: Your answer only addresses creating a type dynamically to replace `Tuple`, which OP did not really have trouble with. They need to know how to deal with dynamic types in a generic list. Address that in your answer and you're good to go (of course, I already answered that ;) )

Comment: @HackedByChinese, well, I add some edits... Also I'm not sure that your code will work... Such dynamic object initialization (`new {Tank = new Tank(), AttackingTank = new Tank()}`) is not supported.

Comment: `dynamic` works fine with anonymous types, provided you observe the general limitations of anonymous types. For example: if OP were to return the resulting list as part of a method, there would likely be problems consuming that result from other assemblies (since anon types are internal, I believe). In that case, your `ExpandoObject` would be necessary, however at that point it becomes mute because OP should use a proper tuple class to better express the API.

Answer (score 1):

Or even more simple

```
        var tupleList = (
           new[] {
                new { fruit = "Tomato", colour = "red"},
                new { fruit = "Tomato", colour = "yellow"},
                new { fruit = "Apple", colour = "red"},
                new { fruit = "Apple", colour = "green"},
                new { fruit = "Medlar", colour = "russet"}
            }).ToList();
```

Which loses the static function.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add one more handy bit here.  I use Alex's answer on occasion, but it drives me a bit nuts trying to track it back down when I need it, since it's not obvious (I find myself searching for "new {").

So I added the following little static method (I wish I could make it an extension method, but of what type?):

```
public static List<T> CreateEmptyListOf<T>(Func<T> itemCreator)
{
    return Enumerable
        .Empty<object>()
        .Select(o => itemCreator())
        .ToList();
}
```

This isolates the part that is different each time I need this pattern from those that are the same.  I call it like this:

```
var emptyList = Ext.CreateEmptyListOf(() => new { Name = default(string), SomeInt = default(int) });
```

Comment: Regarding your question: You can replace the method body with `return new List<T>();`. Now you don't need `Func<T>` any more but only `T` so you can change the parameter definition to `this T itemSample`. Voilà an extension method for any type.

Comment: Yeah, that works too.  It does have a (probably inconsequential) side-effect: you do have to actually create an instance in order to create the list.  Both are a bit confusing to see in the code.  Using your method would look like this: `var emptyList = new { Name = default(string), SomeInt = default(int) }.CreateEmptyListOf();` which I don't prefer; it looks like I'm creating something when I'm not really.  But that's really just an opinion.  Really the best would be if there was a built-in extension or operator.

Comment: Both code is creating one object on the heap: Either a delegate or a stub anonymous object. Really the best is to use real classes and keep the usage of anonymous classes to implicit or explicit LINQ chains.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of objects:

```
List<object> myList = new List<object>();
```

Then add the anonymous type to your list:

```
myList.Add(new {Name = "me", phone = 123});
```